# Is it my NN setting random weights on each iteration?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have defined the following function that creates my NN:

```
def nn_layer(input_tensor, output_dim, layer_name, act=tf.nn.relu):
    # Adding a name scope ensures logical grouping of the layers in the graph.
    with tf.name_scope(layer_name):
        # This Variable will hold the state of the weights for the layer
        with tf.name_scope('weights'):
            weights = weight_variable([input_tensor.get_shape().as_list()[1], output_dim])
            variable_summaries(weights)
        with tf.name_scope('biases'):
            biases = bias_variable([output_dim])
            variable_summaries(biases)
        with tf.name_scope('Wx_plus_b'):
            preactivate = tf.matmul(input_tensor, weights) + biases
            tf.summary.histogram('pre_activations', preactivate)
        activations = act(preactivate, name='activation')
        tf.summary.histogram('activations', activations)

        return activations


def neural_net(features):
    ''' Model function for the NN '''
    input_layer = tf.cast(features, tf.float32)

    hidden_layer = nn_layer(input_layer, 2, 'hidden_layer', act=tf.nn.relu)

    out_layer = nn_layer(hidden_layer, 2, 'out_layer', act=tf.nn.relu)

    return out_layer
```

Then I can compute the logits value with:

```
logits = neural_net(x)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)
sess = tf.Session()

for epoch in range(epochs):
    loss,_ = sess.run([loss, train_step], feed_dict={x: x})
```

I am wondering if this would create a new NN each time I call the run method. If this is true how could I create the network and make it constant through the whole training?

Please have in mind I tried to simplify the code as much as I could

Comment: did you define your model inside the graph?

Comment: Your title talks about random weights, your content talks about creating NN every call, can you be clear?

Comment: I think that's exactly the point of my question, I am not sure about how to do this @Eliethesaiyan

Comment: Well @vijaym it is a matter of perception, if it is creating a new NN then random weights are being set on each iteration, so I think I am being clear

Comment: not sure if its the reason though, if you are running your model only once and print the weight, they will always be different,assuming that your weights are initialzed...i think it would be helpul if you could post all your codes...there are parts that are missing we can't guess about it..especially about the optimizer and your training loop ,put as much code as possible about those , about the graph...by default tf consider one implicity graph(if not mistaken) here is example on how to use a Graph https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph

Comment: I have edited my question following your instructions. I think that the keypoint in here is **how to create the network inside a function**

Comment: @m33n, not true, calling neural_net(x) in a loop will create multiple graph, but the first graph will not be reset with random weights every time.

Comment: The above code will work fine. To check whether the graph is created multiple times use `print(tf.trainable_variables())`.

Comment: I just get hidden layer and output variables. So I guess the graph is only created once (tensors do not override each other right?).

Comment: yes, if there are multiple copies of NN then the variables will have names with underscores, ex: var, var_1, var_2, etc